# Write javascript code into a js using fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I'm trying to write JavaScript code into a js with Nodejs fs module. I managed to write a json file but could wrap my head around on how to write JavaScript to it.

```
 fs.writeFile("config.json", JSON.stringify({name: 'adman'tag: 'batsman',age: 25}), 'utf8',{ flag: "wx" }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  });
```

I need to create a **.js** file with the following data

```
const cricketers = [
    {
        name: 'adman',
        tag: 'batsman',
        age: 25
    },
    // other objects
]

module.exports = cricketers ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. If all you want to do is to be able to do `let someData = require('someFile.json');` Nodejs already supports requiring json files and treats them like Js objects.
2. Otherwise I don't know of a library that will do exactly this for you, BUT...

You can do this yourself. The fs.writeFile function takes a string, so you just have to generate the string you want to write to the file.

```
let someData = [{name: 'adman', tag: 'batsman', age: 25}];
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(someData);
let codeStr = `const cricketers = ${jsonData}; module.exports = cricketers;`;
fs.writeFile("someFile.js", codeStr, 'utf8',{ flag: "wx" }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Obviously this only works for a very specific use case, but the point is it can be done with simple (or complicated...) string manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

use string templating

```
const data = `const cricketers = ${JSON.stringify(yourArray)};
module.exports = cricketers;
`
```

Where `yourArray` is an array of objects